# sub count of column values after group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'org':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],
  'product_version':['bpm','bpm','bpm','bpm','ppp','ppp'],
  'release_date':['2022-07','2022-07','2022-07','2022-07','2022-08','2022-08'],
  'date_avail':['no','no','no','yes','no','no'],
  'status':['green','green','yellow','yellow','green','green']
})
```

that looks like that:

```
  org product_version release_date date_avail  status
0   a             bpm      2022-07         no   green
1   a             bpm      2022-07         no   green
2   a             bpm      2022-07         no  yellow
3   a             bpm      2022-07        yes  yellow
4   b             ppp      2022-08         no   green
5   b             ppp      2022-08         no   green
```

I would like to have the total count after groupinp by columns `['org','product_version','release_date']` . This is straightforward:

```
print(df.groupby(['org','product_version','release_date']).size())

org  product_version  release_date
a    bpm              2022-07         4
b    ppp              2022-08         2
```

However I would like also to get sub-count from this group for the different values of the other columns that were not grouped. For example, first group which has `4` as total count is `a bpm 2022-07` . This group has `3` `no` and `1` `yes` for column `date_avail` and `2` `green` and `2` `yellow` for column `status`.

So my desired table result would look like:

```
org product release_date total number_of_no number_of_yes number_of_green number_of_yellow
a   bpm     2022-07      4     3             1            2               2
b   ppp     2022-08      2     2             0            2               0
```

Comment: could there be other values in `status` except `green` and `yellow` ?

Comment: Yes, could be.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `agg` method in a grouped dataframe to compute multiple aggregation functions for each group. Assuming the only possible colors are green and yellow, it would be something like this:

```py
grouped = df.groupby(['org', 'product_version', 'release_date'])
result = grouped.agg(
    total=('org', 'count'),
    number_of_no=('date_avail', lambda x: (x == 'no').sum()),
    number_of_yes=('date_avail', lambda x: (x == 'yes').sum()),
    number_of_green=('status', lambda x: (x == 'green').sum()),
    number_of_yellow=('status', lambda x: (x == 'yellow').sum())
).reset_index()

print(result)
```

Output:

```py
  org product_version release_date  total  number_of_no  number_of_yes  number_of_green  number_of_yellow
0   a             bpm      2022-07      4             3              1                2                 2
1   b             ppp      2022-08      2             2              0                2                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
groupby_cols = ["org", "product_version", "release_date"]
g = df.groupby(groupby_cols)
out = pd.concat(
    [
        g[col].value_counts().unstack()
        for col in df.columns.drop(groupby_cols)
    ]
).fillna(0).groupby(groupby_cols).sum().reset_index().assign(total=g.size().values)
print(out)



  org product_version release_date   no  yes  green  yellow  total
0   a             bpm      2022-07  3.0  1.0    2.0     2.0      4
1   b             ppp      2022-08  2.0  0.0    2.0     0.0      2
```

And you don't need to worry about the values in the columns to aggregate and sum. You just use value_counts and it will be taken care of.

Or you can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) like:

```
index_series = [df[col] for col in groupby_cols]
columns_series = [df[col] for col in other_cols]
ct = pd.crosstab(index_series, columns_series)
out = pd.concat(
    [ct.groupby(level=l, axis=1).sum() for l in range(ct.columns.nlevels)], axis=1
).assign(total=df.groupby(groupby_cols).size().values)
print(out)

  org product_version release_date  no  yes  green  yellow  total
0   a             bpm      2022-07   3    1      2       2      4
1   b             ppp      2022-08   2    0      2       0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

With a single `df.groupby` and constructing inner `pd.Series` with *total* and *value counts* for each group:

```
cols = ['org','product_version','release_date']
res = df.groupby(cols).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'total': x.index.size}
                                                 | {k: v for c in x.columns[~x.columns.isin(cols)]
                                                  for k, v in x[c].value_counts().to_dict().items()})
                             .to_frame().T).droplevel(len(cols)).reset_index().fillna(0)
print(res)
```

---

```
  org product_version release_date  total  no  yes  green  yellow
0   a             bpm      2022-07      4   3  1.0      2     2.0
1   b             ppp      2022-08      2   2  0.0      2     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `pd.get_dummies()`

```
c = ['org','product_version','release_date']

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df,columns = df.columns.difference(c))

df2.groupby(c).agg(**{i:(i,'sum') for i in df2.columns.difference(c)},count = ('org','count')).reset_index()
```